# data frame and list operation

Tags: python, list, dataframe

There are three columns in `df`: `mins`, `maxs`, and `col`. I would like to generate a binary list according to the following rule: if `col[i]` is smaller than or equal to `mins[i]`, add a "1" to the list and keep adding "1" for each row until `col[i+n]` is greater than or equal `maxs[i+n]`. After reaching `maxs[i+n]`, add "0" to the list for each row until finding the next row where `col[i]` is smaller than or equal to `mins[i]`. Repeat this entire process till going over all rows.

For example,

```
col  mins maxs
 2    1    6   (0)
 4    2    6   (0)
 2    3    7   (1)
 5    5    6   (1)
 4    3    8   (1)
 4    2    5   (1)
 5    3    5   (0)
 4    0    5   (0)
 3    3    8   (1)
......
```

So the list would be `[0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1]`. Does this make sense?

I gave it a shot and wrote the following, which unfortunately did not achieve what I wanted.

```
def get_list(col, mins, maxs):
    l = []
    i = 0
    while i <= len(col):
        if col[i] <= mins[i]:
            l.append(1)
            while col[i+1] <= maxs[i+1]:
                l.append(1)
                i += 1
            break
        break
    return l
```

Thank you so much folks!

Comment: please don't use builtin types as variable names

Comment: yes i realized right away after posting (and seeing the font in blue), just edited it! Thanks!

Comment: i mean in the function definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My answer may not be elegant but should work according to your expectation.

1. Import the pandas library.

   ```py
   import pandas as pd
   ```
2. Create dataframe according to data provided.

   ```py
   input_data = {
       'col': [2, 4, 2, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3],
       'mins': [1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 2 , 3, 0, 3],
       'maxs': [6, 6, 7, 6, 8, 5, 5, 5, 8]
   }
   dataframe_ = pd.DataFrame(data=input_data)
   ```
3. Using a for loop iterate over the rows. The `switch` variable will change accordingly depending on the conditions was provided which results in the `binary` column being populated.

   ```py
    binary_switch = False

    for index, row in dataframe_.iterrows():

        if row['col'] <= row['mins']:
            binary_switch = True
        elif row['col'] >= row['maxs']:
            binary_switch = False

        binary_output = 1 if binary_switch else 0

        dataframe_.at[index, 'binary'] = binary_output

    dataframe_['binary'] = dataframe_['binary'].astype('int')
    print(dataframe_)
   ```
4. Output from code.

   ```
        col   mins  maxs  binary
    0    2     1     6       0
    1    4     2     6       0
    2    2     3     7       1
    3    5     5     6       1
    4    4     3     8       1
    5    4     2     5       1
    6    5     3     5       0
    7    4     0     5       0
    8    3     3     8       1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your rules give the following decision tree:
1: is `col <= mins`?
`True`: `l.append(1)`
`False`: next question
2: was `col <= mins` before?
`False`: `l.append(0)`
`True`: next question:
3: is `col >= maxs`?
`True`: `l.append(0)`
`False`: `l.append(1)`

Making this into a function with an `if/else` tree, you get this:

```
def make_binary_list(df):
    l = []
    col_lte_mins = False
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        col  = row["col"]
        mins = row["mins"]
        maxs = row["maxs"]

        if col <= mins:
            col_lte_mins = True
            l.append(1)
        else:
            if col_lte_mins:
                if col >= maxs:
                    col_lte_mins = False
                    l.append(0)
                else:
                    l.append(1)
            else:
                l.append(0)
    return l
```

`make_binary_list(df)` gives `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]`